# Does my dual core AMD Athlon 64 X2 4400+ support AMD-V?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, 64-bit, central-processing-unit

I am trying to setup some VM's on Citrix XenServer but can't enable Hardware Virtualization support. In the XenServer install it prompted me to enable this, and upon creating a VM I got a "HVM required" error.

I have a dual core AMD Athlon 64 X2 4400+ processor - does this have support for AMD-V?

How can I enable this to run this software/VM's?

If it helps I am running:

- a Mach Speed MSNV-939 motherboard
  with 3 gigs of RAM.
- Pheonix Technologies 6.0 BIOS

**Edit:** It looks like the chip can do it, but not with the 939 socket, I need the AM2 socket. Can anyone confirm this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AMD added hardware virtualization with the AM2 socket.  Your current chip is made for socket 939 and does not support hardware virtualization.

Comment: Well from what I've read the AM2 and AM2+ socket configurations support the chip I have. Does this mean I have the right chip, just the wrong socket config?

Comment: @barfoon: Run CPU-Z to identify socket type as well as the stepping.

http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php

Comment: The x2 4400+ was made for both socket 939 and AM2.  The AM2 version supports virtualization, but the 939 version (which I believe you have due to the 939 in your motherboard model) does not support it.

Comment: +1 upvote as your comments contain correct information. You should update your response to include that. I think this is the reason for the downvote as you dont provide insight into your conclusion

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it have. You should look at `svm` flag in your `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Here is the output from my system that uses this processor (two lines are for two cores):

```
$ grep svm /proc/cpuinfo 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SecurAble](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm) to determine if your processor has Hardware Virtualization support.

[image]

If you can't use SecurAble then try looking in the BIOS as it can be disabled by default.

[This article](http://www.techfuels.com/motherboards-memory/11355-amd-athlon-64-x2-4400-a.html) says that your Athlon 64 X2 4400+ has HV.

Comment: I cant use SecurAble ATM - windows isnt installed on the machine...

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo on Linux. Look for vmx flag.

Comment: nothing* is installed on the machine right now...

Answer (score 0):

According to wiki "AMD-V capability is also available on Athlon 64 and Athlon 64 X2 family of processors with **"F" or "G" stepping** on socket AM2" so not all AM2 CPUs support AMD-V.

You can make sure with of CPU stepping via [AMDCompare.com](http://www.amdcompare.com/) website.

Comment: Yeah, I read the wiki - what does "F" or "G" mean??

Comment: CPU stepping is the "revision number" for that model of CPU. Revision level represents when it was manufactured. The more recent the CPU stepping, the more features or more energy-efficient it is even though the speed is the same.